# Django restrict other users from editing posts

Tags: django

I have an update view that is working properly. The only issue is currently anyone can edit any post. To solve this issue I implemented the `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin`. I believe I have implemented it correctly but any one is still able to edit any post.

view:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostFormUpdate
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of superclasses extended matters, so `UserPassesTestMixin` should come before `UpdateView`:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
```

I'm surprised that this is not mentioned in the documentation for `UserPassesTestMixin`, but you can get the hint from [`LoginRequired`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin):

> This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list.

As a side note you can simply do

```
return self.request.user == post.author
```

As it is already a boolean value. No need for an `if` clause.